# sever slide validation active js function

Tags: javascript, php

```
function checkpassword(){
    var password_value = $("#reg-password").val();

    if(password_value === ""){
        //password emtpy
        $("#password-result").html('Please make a password');
        $("#password-result").css('color', 'red');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', 'red');
    }else if (password_value.length < 6){
        //password is too shot 6 digi
        $("#password-result").html('Your password is too short.');
        $("#password-result").css('color', 'red');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', 'red');
    }else{
        //password passed
        $("#password-result").html('');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', '#dfe0e6');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is a validation function with client side , i wanted to make a sever side which will active the this function , exp if

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(empty($_POST['submit'])){
//some how active js (password_value === "");
}
}
```

how should i make those or i am making this validation wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `if(empty($_POST['submit'])){` loop is not needed. But it makes no sense running a JavaScript function with PHP.

JavaScript validation is running before the PHP validation i.e. you must call the function client-side with JavaScript.

If you want to check the password, while the user types, AJAX is the way to go! Here you call a PHP script with JavaScript code.

Example: http://www.shawngo.com/examples/ajax-username-check/

Answer (score 0):

Simple!! write your php and javaScript in same file like this

```
<?php

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkpassword(){
    var password_value = $("#reg-password").val();

    if(password_value === ""){
        //password emtpy
        $("#password-result").html('Please make a password');
        $("#password-result").css('color', 'red');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', 'red');
    }else if (password_value.length < 6){
        //password is too shot 6 digi
        $("#password-result").html('Your password is too short.');
        $("#password-result").css('color', 'red');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', 'red');
    }else{
        //password passed
        $("#password-result").html('');
        $('#reg-password').css('border-color', '#dfe0e6');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

</script>

//Your form.....
//Your form .....
//Your form .....
//Your form.....

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "checkpassword();";
    }
}
?>
```

this will activate your JS function.